# Как создать путь к элементу ассоциируемого массива(объекта) с возможностью редактирования?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть ассоциируемого массив(объект).

```
    var test_array = {
    "things":{
      "equipment":{
        "car":{
          "id1":   "00",
        "id2":   "01" 
        },
        "engine":{
          "id3":   "02",
        "id4":   "03" 
        }
      },
      "organics":{
        "flor":{
          "id5":   "04",
        "id6":   "05" 
        },
        "mushrooms":{
          "id7":   "06",
        "id8":   "07" 
        }
      }
    }
    };
```

И сохраненый путь к элементу в виде массива.

```
     var way = ['things','equipment','car']
```

И я хочу с помощью метода forEach добраться до элемента массива test_array

Аналог

```
      test_array['things']['equipment']['car']
```

Для дальнейшего редактирования. Добавления и удаления элементов.

Я пробовал так

```
    array_clone2 = test_array; 
    way.push($(this).attr("id")) 
    way.forEach(function(element) {
    array_clone2  = array_clone2[element];
    });
    console.log(array_clone2);
```

Но я понял что я создаю лишь копию массива и удалить какой либо элемент из основного не получится.
Есть ли у кого решение как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хоть в javascript объекты это ассоциативные массивы, но их не принято называть массивы, о них говорят просто **объект**

что касается вопроса, то вот примерно такой функцией можно достать объект по пути:

```
function get(o, w) {  
   return w.reduce((a,e) => a[e], o);
}

function del(o, w) {  
  w.forEach((p, i) => i + 1< w.length ? o = o[p] : delete o[p]); 
}
```

---

```js
var test_array = {
  "things":{
    "equipment":{
      "car":{
        "id1":   "00",
        "id2":   "01" 
      },
      "engine":{
        "id3":   "02",
        "id4":   "03" 
      }
    },
    "organics":{
      "flor":{
        "id5":   "04",
        "id6":   "05" 
      },
      "mushrooms":{
        "id7":   "06",
        "id8":   "07" 
      }
    }
  }
};

var way = ['things', 'equipment', 'car'];

get(test_array, way).example = 123;

function del(o, w) {  
  w.forEach((p, i) => i + 1< w.length ? o = o[p] : delete o[p]); 
}

function get(o, w) {  
  return w.reduce((a,e) => a[e], o);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(test_array));

del(test_array, way)

console.log(JSON.stringify(test_array));
```

Comment: А как тогда удалить например car  не меняя way единственное что я смог так это `var way = ['things','equipment'] get(test_array, way).car =  undefined;` Но так слегка неудобно

Comment: @zeni1agent добавил функцию del

Comment: К стати у тебя опечатка в слове return

Comment: @zeni1agent очень странно, поправил :)

Comment: `reduce` тут смотрелся бы намного красивее :-) и без всяких `if` :)

Comment: @Grundy да, Вы правы, надо переделать, переделал

Comment: `del(o,w)=>delete (get(o,w.slice(0,-1))[w.pop()])`

Comment: @Grundy там было нежелание менять `w` в хотелках

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, решается заменой `pop` :) хотел вот так: `(o,[...path,key])=>delete (get(o,path)[key])` - но так нельзя :) а было б красиво

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test_array = {
    "things":{
      "equipment":{
        "car":{
          "id1":   "00",
        "id2":   "01" 
        },
        "engine":{
          "id3":   "02",
        "id4":   "03" 
        }
      },
      "organics":{
        "flor":{
          "id5":   "04",
        "id6":   "05" 
        },
        "mushrooms":{
          "id7":   "06",
        "id8":   "07" 
        }
      }
    }
  };
  
  var way = ['things','equipment','car'];
  
  let res = null;
  
  f(test_array,way,0);
  
  console.log(res);
  
  function f(obj, way, n){
    if (way.length === n) return;
    res = obj[way[n]];
    f(obj[way[n]],way,n+=1);
  }
```